# UISplitViewController: Deinit DetailView in collapsed mode

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, dealloc, deinit

I've been struggling on this for a while now, but I wasn't able to find a solution:

I've got an iOS 9 app that supports all device families, uses size classes and is programmed with Swift 2.0.
I'm using a `UISplitViewController` and everything works as I want, except in a collapsed environment (e.g. on an iPhone).

The Master-ViewController is a `UITableViewController` that triggers a replace segue when a cell is selected. In a collapsed environment this means, that the detailViewcontroller gets pushed onto the screen. The `UISplitViewController` visually behaves kind of like a `UINavigationController`. 
However, when I dismiss the detailViewController with the back button or the swipe gesture it does not get deallocated until the a new replace segue is triggered in the Master-ViewController.

I assume that this is kind of a feature of `UISplitViewController`, since it was originally designed to show both contents next to each other. Nevertheless, in a collapsed environment I would like my `UISplitViewController` to behave like a simple `UINavigationController`, which deallocates the previously pushed detailviewController when popped.

I've been trying to manually change the splitViewController's `viewControllers` attribute after the detailViewController is popped:

```
 if let firstVc = self.splitViewController?.viewControllers.first {
        self.splitViewController?.viewControllers = [firstVc]
 }
```

But that does not help. Simply replacing the detailViewController with an empty "Dummy"-ViewController doesn't work neither, since it automatically animates the transition.
Playing around with the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` didn't help me neither...

Is there a solution for this (maybe simple? :)), that I'm too blind to see?

Comment: If you've solved this problem, please add the answer. This will help other users.

Comment: @Tushar unfortunately I didn't solve it yet. Had to built a workaround

Comment: @croX can you give a brief explanation of your workaround?

Comment: @SAHM, the workaround was basically to handle this situation manually on the detailViewController, meaning that I had to stop all active tasks/calculation, etc. and only to run them when the screen was actually visible.